# How to show POST data from external url api to my blade file

Tags: laravel, api, http, payment-gateway

External site data to be displayed on my blade

```
MerchantCode
MerchantRefNo
Particulars
Amount
PayorName
PayorEmail
Status
RefNo
```

Here's my Controller

```
function getPaymentDetail()
    {
        
        $data = Http::get('https://external.com/api')->json();
        
        return view('paymentdetails',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would code it like this.

In your controller.

```
function getPaymentDetail() {

    $res = Http::get('https://external.com/api')->json();

    $temp_data = json_decode($temp_data, TRUE);

    foreach($temp_data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    return view('paymentdetails', $data);
}
```

In your blade file, you can access by `{{ $MerchantCode }}`

Comment: i followed what you said and i got ```Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".```